# Developer Options not showing up in LineageOS new build

Tags: 7.0-nougat, lineageos, developer-options

Some weeks back I installed the latest version of LineageO S: 14.1-20170209-UNOFFICIAL-onyx on my One Plus X phone. After playing around with it, there were a lot of issues in the new build. So I decided to uninstall it by opening the Developer Options and tapping 7 times on the build number, but nothing comes up.

Below are the things which are not working in the new build:

- Tapping build number 7 times doesn't unlock Developer Options
- No notifications at all. I can hear the sounds but no success to show notifications
- Google Play Store updates & installation suddenly stopped
- Reset everything option not working

How to open Developer Options so that I can activate the bootloader & install the stable ROM?

Comment: Can't you just use `adb reboot-bootloader` from a PC?

Answer (score 2):

We have a potential [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here...

Instead of trying your utmost to get into developer options, just power off the phone fully, then use the key combo `POWER + VOLUME_UP` to boot into bootloader, from which you can start tackling the problem in ways you'd like.